# (DONE) Can question #21407 be improved and reopened?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, scope, closed-questions, reopen-request

Thanks to many edits (and last great one from @avazula), this [question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/21407/is-it-common-courtesy-to-leave-a-gift-behind-someones-door) about "courtesy" has been (temporarly) saved and could probably be reopened.

"*Is it common to leave something in someone's house and expect them to think it's a gift for them?*" is part of the "*non-verbal communication*" skill, and has a lot to teach to people who won't easily pick up the clues when it's not directly said or written.

It's a very good example of how hard it is to understand people's meanings. It leads to misunderstandings, can ruin relationships, and let some people puzzled. Thoughtful gestures, or small gesture having big impact, it seems important that people who have no knowledge/understanding about these can get some input.

If the question (or its answer) can still be improved, please share your opinions/ideas.

---

**Update**: thanks to who edited/improved/voted to reopen. Anyone with a better idea (yeah, I know, it's going to be an off-topic phrasing request ^^) about how we could make the title match the body and the ideas behind OP's concerns?

Comment: I think it looks pretty good as it is. I can see where some people might still want to keep it closed because "Is this common" does sound a bit too opinion based. That being said, I think that from reading the rest of the question it's clear that the question is more about understanding the behavior, so I've voted to reopen. The only change I might make is rewording the last sentence if it stays closed.

Comment: Don't you feel that "Is it common" is some kind of opinion-based question? And under what section of your on-topic subject would you put this question? Academic-research?

Comment: "Is it common" may not be opinion-based at all, if OP doesn't know the specific etiquette about the topic / the culture. Like the huge surprise I got, in the US, first time I ate at someone's, and they put their hand on their lap while eating! I would have asked "is it common to do that?!" (as it was the exact opposite of my culture). I learnt, and did the same after, to be polite and respect their culture. But you have to understand first. Here, it's not about "academic-research". Rather... culture? communication? I have to say I can't find the proper tag though...